# java - Keeping track of input in for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have to take in user input for three integers and compare those integers. This is the code I have so far but I think I could increase readability through a for loop, however I'm not sure how to keep track of everything they enter to be able to compare them.

```
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int int1 = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int int2 = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int int3 = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
```

EDIT: I just realized I can also do the following, but my question about tracking through for loops still stands.

```
    System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
    int int1 = console.nextInt();
    int int2 = console.nextInt();
    int int3 = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Keep the answers in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] x = new int[3];
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    x[i] = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: Beat me too it. +1 :P

Comment: Ah okay, we haven't learned about arrays just yet, but good to know it is possible!

Comment: @Matt Was half guessing, since Java isn't my strength

Comment: Let me tack on one thing about arrays then just so you know. If you use array, you are setting a **STATIC (does not change after initialized)** length of the array to put data. You can use ArrayList<int> and that is a **DYNAMIC (can change after initialized)** array that is a class and can change the size of the array as you go. You'll probably learn more about it, just wanted to give you a heads up.

Comment: @Matt Yep, that could be useful info for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it by using an array.

```
int[] array = new int[3];  //this is an array

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
System.out.println("Enter an integer: \n");
 array[i] = console.nextInt();  // here it will store the int values in array[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind would be to store the inputs in an int array. For example:

```
int[] input = new int[3]; // Whatever size you want
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i] = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple as that

```
System.out.print("Enter three integers: ");
int int1 = console.nextInt();
int int2 = console.nextInt();
int int3 = console.nextInt();


if (int1 == int2 && int2 == int3) System.out.println("Integers are the same");
else System.out.println("Integers are different");
```